# javax.usb : Number of attached devices is always zero

Tags: java, usb

I have searched and searched SO, Google, etc. and everywhere I get code that is approximately similar to the one below. For example, I tried [this](https://github.com/Synesso/Monci). I tried running it with root and otherwise. But, the number of attached devices is always zero. Can you give me a clue as to why this could be happening ?

This is on Ubuntu-12.04, 32-bit.

Java code:

```
    package com.me.test;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.usb.UsbDevice;
    import javax.usb.UsbDisconnectedException;
    import javax.usb.UsbException;
    import javax.usb.UsbHostManager;
    import javax.usb.UsbHub;
    import javax.usb.UsbServices;

    public class ListUsbDevices {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, UsbException, UnsupportedEncodingException, UsbDisconnectedException {
            UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
            UsbHub rootHub = services.getRootUsbHub();

            List<UsbDevice> devices = rootHub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
            if (devices.size()>0) {
                System.out.println("USB devices found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No USB devices found.");
            }

            for (UsbDevice device : devices) {
                System.out.println("\tProduct String " + device.getProductString());
                System.out.println("\tManufacturer String " + device.getManufacturerString());
                System.out.println("\tSerial Number " + device.getSerialNumberString());
            }


        }
    }
```

lsusb output:

```
    user@host:~$ sudo lsusb
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 010: ID 03eb:2013 Atmel Corp. 
    user@host:~$ sudo lsusb -s 4:10 -v
    Bus 004 Device 010: ID 03eb:2013 Atmel Corp. 
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.00
      bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        32
      idVendor           0x03eb Atmel Corp.
      idProduct          0x2013 
      bcdDevice           10.00
      iManufacturer           1 AppliedSensor
      iProduct                2 iAQ Stick
      iSerial                 0 
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           41
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0x80
          (Bus Powered)
        MaxPower              100mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
          iInterface              0 
            HID Device Descriptor:
              bLength                 9
              bDescriptorType        33
              bcdHID               1.11
              bCountryCode            0 Not supported
              bNumDescriptors         1
              bDescriptorType        34 Report
              wDescriptorLength      53
             Report Descriptors: 
               ** UNAVAILABLE **
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
            bInterval              10
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
            bInterval              10
    Device Status:     0x0000
      (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: May be such a service turned off by administrator?

Comment: What implementation of `javax.usb` are you using?

Comment: @RomanC I am running on my laptop; so, nothing about administrator. Code Painters, I am using Linux implementation.

Comment: @cogitoergosum Did you test it on Windows? Are you administrator, no, go to the administrator.

Comment: @RomanC, I am using the Linux implementation from [here](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/). No Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The javax.usb stuff can depend a lot on the flavor of linux you are running, and your machine's configuration in general.

You should try downloading and running the example programs, [here on sourceforge](http://javax-usb.cvs.sourceforge.net/javax-usb/javax-usb-example/), on your machine. If those do not work, then you should assume you'll need to change either the configuration of your machine, or something about your runtime.

I was having some problems with this library, and got [the following recommendations](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/16736-jusb). This information may be quite outdated, but it may help point you in the right direction:

> Once downloaded and built, you need to ensure that libjusb.so gets
>   copied over to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386, and that it has read and
>   evecute permissions for your user. Also ensure that you have the
>   usbdevfs virtual device mounted, and that your user has proper R/W
>   access to it.
>
> Lastly, depending on what USB device you want to talk to, you *may*
>   need to disable hotplug (or at least blacklist any installed modules
>   that may also attempt to talk to your device). If the device already
>   has support in Linux, hotplug will load it's associated module and
>   give it exclusive I/O access before you can grab the device from jUSB.

The above quoted text is from Brad Barclay. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did start off with the samples they have. They failed similarly too. That is when I thought, I will try the 'simplest' attempt. 
Would your comment on [jUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jusb/) be applicable for [javax.usb](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/) too ?

Comment: Your point about hotplug and this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932206/update-list-of-usb-devices) made me look into the `javax.usb.properties` file as required by the Linux JSR-80 implementation. I didn't follow much of it so, just set `com.ibm.jusb.os.linux.LinuxUsbServices.topologyUpdateUsePolling = false`. Running as root, I get an error as `[hotplug](0) JavaxUsbTopologyListener.c.Java_com_ibm_jusb_os_linux_JavaxUsb_nativeTopologyListener[32] Could not open /proc/bus/usb/devices`. I have only `/proc/bus/input` and `/proc/bus/pci`. Any clue ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/156085 ? it seems like a linux specific issue.

Comment: The `mount` command for `/proc/bus/usb` didn't work as it reported a error that the mount point does not exist. I searched around and came across this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1432598) that lists two options. First, use older kernel. I don't know how to do that, as booting does not show an older kernel. Second, compile kernel with usbfs enabled. I am not enough of a Linux geek to do that. I am wondering if it were possible to get `javax.usb` to _not_ look for `/proc/bus/usb` and look elsewhere (yes, but where ?).