# How can I know that some devices have been connected with my computer?

Tags: java

I want to monitor whether a device has been attached to my computer. I can monitor it at **Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers**. But how can I get this info in my Java code? 
The device is been attached with USB port and it's a keyboard and mouse simulator. I use it to remote control other computer

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: you need some native libraries to do that. try https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/

Comment: @GregHewgill. The device is been attached with USB port and it's a keyboard and mouse simulator. I use it to remote control other computer.

Comment: @PM77-1 . I focused on the device's API before but have a really unstable monitor process so that I want to use windows native method to reach my goal. I just don't know where to start now.

Comment: You may want to review [Update list of usb devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932206/update-list-of-usb-devices) as a starting point.

Comment: @Leo, thank you for your remind and it's what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need some native libraries to do that. try

http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi

Comment: I've encountered a problem when I use it. It works fine if I don't open the device. But I have no device by hid_enumerate if I open the device.

Comment: I've asked a new question about this issue and you can reach it by http://stackoverflow.com/q/25173007/3378204